# iPhone communicating with Ruby on Rails web site for login/logout

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication

I'm developing an iPhone app which allows users to login to a web service by using the token and api

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tokens.json?email=tok_apple2009@hotmail.co.uk&password=111111

http://localhost:3000/api/test.json?auth_token=h8uTVFseoMiLvRquK4Vt
```

However I'm having trouble in this part, could anyone could please help me?

Thanks

Comment: You can utilize `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AFNetworking(https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) framework for communicating with webservices.